# Is there BAPI equivalent to transaction CKMM?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, bapi

Is there a BAPI equivalent (or function module equivalent) to SAP transaction `CKMM`?

The goal is to change the price determination programmatically.

Everything I found is about updating price but not about updating price determination in material ledger.

Comment: This looks like some configuration stuff. There are no BAPIs for configuration usually, at least that is what I have experienced. Personally I would make some use of BAPIs for Product Configuration in SAP Banking... unfortunately there is only SAP GUI available...

Comment: Looks like that transaction updates MBEW-MLAST which can also be updated using VALUATIONDATA-ML_SETTLE in BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEDATA.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no BAPI. I am wondering what the requirement here is.. `CKMM` should be a one time setting and it is already a mass change transaction.

Warning! If you change price control back and forth all previous recorded data in material ledger is lost!

So, I strongly advise to rethink your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **LSMW** script (**L**egacy **S**ystem **M**igration **W**orkbench) to run the transaction code [**CKMM**](http://www.sapdatasheet.org/abap/tran/ckmm.html) (Change Price Determination) and fill in parameters and check results via programming.